# ES6: creating an Axios post with parameters

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, axios

I want to have a service called

```
          create(tableName, dataRow, cookie)
```

that will create a new row at tableName with dataRow. The  cookie  is just to verify the person. This service will run at a server with some http address H. So, I believe the link to that service could be:

```
httpLink = H + '/create'           (concatenating using ES6)
```

and my axios post will be like:

```
axios.post(
   httpLink, dataRow
)
```

but I don't see how to specify the tableName parameter nor the cookie one at the Axios request. Can this be done? Is there a better way? Please, let me know
Thanks

Comment: FWIW, `httpLink = H + '/create'  ` is also valid in ES5, so I'm not sure what you think is ES6 specific about it.

Comment: for the create service I need to specify the tableName and cookie parameters also through the same Axios POST call. I can't find out how.

Comment: I understand. Have a look at the options you can pass to a request: https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#request-config . It's up to you to decide how you want to send the data (e.g. both the row data and the table name as post parameters or the table name as get parameter (part of the URL)). That also depends on what your server expects if you have built it already.  E.g. you could do `axios.post(url, {dataRow, tableName})`.